# Forwarding email based on attachment name

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using Outlook 2010 and I am trying to forward emails to specific users based on the attachment name. The code below works, except that I have to create a rule in Outlook for each different attachment name (I eventually run out of storage for my rules, even after increasing the rules size to 256kb in exchange console).

I would like this script to run under one rule. It would need to be something like.... if the attachment name is "xxxxx.pdf" then send to "name@domain.com" if not then skip, if the attachment name is "xx.xls" then send to "name1@domain.com" if not then skip....and so on...

Below is what I have so far, I would like it all combined.

Code pasted in Outlook session:

```
Sub SendOnMessage23(olItem As MailItem)
Dim olAtt As Attachment, yest As Boolean, ol_newmail As MailItem
For Each olAtt In olItem.Attachments
    If InStr(1, olAtt.FileName, "Print_Ack_Rpt.rpt_1100023-1") > 0 Then yest = True: Exit For
NextIf yest = True Then
    Set ol_newmail = olItem.Forward
        ol_newmail.To = "user@domain.com"
        ol_newmail.Send
End If
End Sub

Sub SendOnMessage23(olItem As MailItem)
Dim olAtt As Attachment, yest As Boolean, ol_newmail As MailItem
For Each olAtt In olItem.Attachments
    If InStr(1, olAtt.FileName, "Print_Ack_Rpt.rpt_1100024-1") > 0 Then yest = True: Exit For
NextIf yest = True Then
    Set ol_newmail = olItem.Forward
        ol_newmail.To = "user1@domain.com"
        ol_newmail.Send
End If
End Sub

Sub SendOnMessage23(olItem As MailItem)
Dim olAtt As Attachment, yest As Boolean, ol_newmail As MailItem
For Each olAtt In olItem.Attachments
    If InStr(1, olAtt.FileName, "Print_Ack_Rpt.rpt_1100024-1") > 0 Then yest = True: Exit For
NextIf yest = True Then
    Set ol_newmail = olItem.Forward
        ol_newmail.To = "user2@domain.com"
        ol_newmail.Send
End If
End Sub

Sub SendOnMessage23(olItem As MailItem)
Dim olAtt As Attachment, yest As Boolean, ol_newmail As MailItem
For Each olAtt In olItem.Attachments
    If InStr(1, olAtt.FileName, "Print_Ack_Rpt.rpt_1100024-1") > 0 Then yest = True: Exit For
NextIf yest = True Then
    Set ol_newmail = olItem.Forward
        ol_newmail.To = "user3@domain.com"
        ol_newmail.Send
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking to utilize the `ElseIf` condition. It also seems like you're not properly utilizing the `If` condition as it was intended.

**A Suggestion For Your Current Subs**

In an `If` statement, when the argument is satisfied the code beneath it and before the `EndIf` condition will run. So instead of setting the `yest` variable to `True` and exiting the loop, you could just insert the code you want to run when the argument is true beneath the `If` statement. When the condition is true the email will forward, and when it is not the code will move onto the next attachment to see if it satisfies your `If` statement.

For your first sub the code would look something like this:

```
Sub SendOnMessage23(olItem As MailItem)
Dim olAtt As Attachment, ol_newmail As MailItem

For Each olAtt In olItem.Attachments
    If InStr(1, olAtt.FileName, "Print_Ack_Rpt.rpt_1100023-1") > 0 Then
        Set ol_newmail = olItem.Forward
        ol_newmail.To = "user@domain.com"
        ol_newmail.Send
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I also included an `Exit` clause after it finds a satisfactory attachment so that it does not send out multiple emails if for some reason you have two attachments that meet the condition.

**Combining Everything Into One Sub**

Now that we have the `If` statement working we can start combining your subs into one using `ElseIf`. Basically `ElseIf` works on the principle that when the condition tested before it is false, it then gets a shot at testing its condition. So in this instance, when your `If` statement is not satisfied the `ElseIf` below checks to see if its condition is satisfied. When it is it executes its code, and when it isn't the code proceeds to the next line. You can add as many `ElseIf`s as you need and they will check their conditions in sequential order. We'll take advantage of this to combine all your subs into one like so:

```
Sub SendOnMessage23(olItem As MailItem)
Dim olAtt As Attachment, ol_newmail As MailItem

For Each olAtt In olItem.Attachments
    If InStr(1, olAtt.FileName, "Print_Ack_Rpt.rpt_1100023-1") > 0 Then
        Set ol_newmail = olItem.Forward
        ol_newmail.To = "user@domain.com"
        ol_newmail.Send
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf InStr(1, olAtt.FileName, "Print_Ack_Rpt.rpt_1100024-1") > 0 Then
        Set ol_newmail = olItem.Forward
        ol_newmail.To = "user1@domain.com"
        ol_newmail.Send
        Exit Sub
    '... keep adding your other subs following the ElseIf format above
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I have not tested any of the above code in Outlook, but if your code was working this should work as well. If not, let me know and we can work through any issues.

Comment: this worked perfect. Thanks for taking the time to clear up and explain the code in detail!!!